# Kernel of a product based on an irreducible, rowstochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a irreducible, rowstochastic $n \times n$ matrix and let $A = (G-I)$ and $B = (G-\lambda I)$, where $|\lambda|\leq 1$ is an arbitrary eigenvalue of $G$. I am interested in learning about the kernel of the matrix $W = AB$.

I know that $Bx = 0 \implies ABx = 0$, such that $\text{ker}(B)\subseteq \text{ker}(AB)$. I am wondering, however, whether it is generally true that both kernels are equal?

If this is the case, it should hold that $\text{im}(B) \cap \text{ker}(A) = \{0\}$. From the Perron-Frobenius theorem, I know that $\text{ker}(A)$ only contains multiples of the unit vector $\iota$. So it should hold that $\text{im}(B) \cap \iota = \{0\}$, or equivalently, $\iota$ belongs to the left kernel of $B$.

But how do I proceed from here?

Edit: I should have mentioned that the diagonal elements of $G$ are all zero, as it is a rownormalized adjacency matrix.

Comment: have you considered the uniform distribution?  i.e. $G:= \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{11}^T$.  it is rank one so $\lambda :=0$ and $\dim \ker B = n-1 \neq n= \ker(AB)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have added to my question that all the diagonal elements of $G$ should be zero, so $G = n^{-1}11^T$ is not allowed. I also know from Perron-Frobenius that $\text{dim }\text{ker } A = 1$ and $\text{dim }\text{ker } B \leq n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(BA)=\ker(AB)$, if you want $\ker(AB)=\ker(B)$, it is necessarily true that $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(B)$. As $G$ is irreducible and row stochastic, $\ker(A)=\operatorname{span}(\{e\})$. But then $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(B)$ only if $\lambda=1$, i.e. only if $A=B$.

Conversely, if $A=B$, since $G$ is irreducible, $0$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A$. It follows that $\ker(AB)=\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it generally true that $\text{ker}(BA) = \text{ker}(AB)$? Or from which property does this follow?

Comment: @Seb No, in general $\ker(AB)\ne\ker(BA)$, but in your case $AB=BA$. Therefore the two null spaces are equal.